# How to escape number in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, capturing-group

So I was replacing characters by `re` module.
I have a string 'abc_def' and need to add `1` after `_`.
So I was doing this.

```
st = 'abc_def'
re.sub(r'^(\w+_)('')(\w+)$',r'\11\3',st)
```

But this takes \11 as 11th captured group, not \1 and 1 separately.

Btw `r\1,1\3` works just as it should, returns `abc_,1def`.

Need help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\g<number>` instead of `\number`:

```
re.sub(r'^(\w+_)('')(\w+)$',r'\g<1>1\3',st)
```